# What version of OC Linux can I use?

Tags: syslinux

I want to try something new. I used Windows for a long time.

> I have sistem: `сore i5-4460` `Asus 1050`.

I was thinking of installing Ubuntu, just her. But amd is written on the installation file, can it work for me?

Which system might work for me? I also use PHPStorm, Photoshop,Steam , FileZilla and OpenServer. What can you suggest and advise. Thank you so much!

Comment: Lots of Ubuntu systems might work for you. Download a few LiveUSBs and try them.

Comment: Photoshop will probably be hard to install in Linux.  If you do not need to use photoshop itself, there are quite a few alternatives to it, like gimp.  Please check with your other programs and see if they work in Linux or have alternatives you can use.  Steam does work in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You chose the right file for your fourth generation Intel Core i5 CPU.

The **AMD** in the Ubuntu ISO file name just means it will run code originally written for the 64-bit AMD processors. Intel adopted that processor design, so when you downloaded the installer, you downloaded the version which will work on either Intel or AMD CPUs.

https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0 shows you how to make the LiveUSB from the ISO file you downloaded, and https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#0 shows you how to install it.